# How to paginate blocks in slack API using javascript

Tags: javascript, slack-api

I have a slack API block array of objects and I want to paginate it so that i can get a limit of 10 items at a time until i get to the last item in the block, like a pagination on a website with `prev` and `next` buttons to navigate. Here is what i have done so far, when ever i click the button the page only increment or decrement ones and the page number remains the same after the first click.

```
let page = 1;
  const limit = 4;

  const startIndex = (page - 1) * limit;
  const endIndex = page * limit;

  const paginatedItem = {
    limit,
    page,
    newPage: items.slice(startIndex, endIndex),
  };


for (const item of paginatedItem.newPage) {
  blocks.push(...)

}

if (paginatedItem.page > 1) {
    blocks.push({
      type: 'actions',
      elements: [
        {
          type: 'button',
          text: {
            type: 'plain_text',
            text: 'Prev',
            emoji: true,
          },
          value: `${page - 1}`,
          action_id: 'command_prev',
        },
      ],
    });
  }

  if (paginatedItem.page < items.length / limit) {
    blocks.push({
      type: 'actions',
      elements: [
        {
          type: 'button',
          text: {
            type: 'plain_text',
            text: 'Next',
            emoji: true,
          },
          value: `${page + 1}`,
          action_id: 'command_next',
        },
      ],
    });
  }
```

when i click the next botton `value: ${page + 1}` always stays at 2, while prev `value: ${page - 1}` stays at 0